# Java+Discord - Creating a transparent frame for Chat Overlay

Tags: java, swing, jframe, discord

So I play Destiny 2, which doesn't allow Discord to inject their overlay code since they don't have cheat protection yet. So what I was trying to accomplish was to create a transparent window, which is set to always be on top, which I could point Discord too in order to have the overlay appear on their instead of the actual Destiny 2 application. My issue is, I can't seem to figure out how to make the discord overlay be stay opaque while the frame is transparent. This is the code I have

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class window {
    public JFrame win = new JFrame("Discord Overlay");

    window(int x, int y){
        win.setUndecorated(true);
        win.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        win.setSize(x, y);
        win.setOpacity(0f);
        win.setVisible(true);
        win.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Timer update = new Timer(10, null);
        update.addActionListener(e -> {
            win.repaint();
        });
        update.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         new window(300, 500);
    }
}
```

As of right now, the overlay matches the opacity of the frame, as I don't fully understand how the discord overlay works, does anyone have any idea of how to bypass this? Thank you.